# Catching an onReleaseOutside for the stage

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, mouseevent

Firstly I feel this question is not a duplicate for :
[Easiest implementation of onReleaseOutside in AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255133/easiest-implementation-of-onreleaseoutside-in-as3)

Now, the problem , I want to do some action when the mouse_down happened inside the stage, but the mouseup happened outside it.
e.g check google finance charts, try dragging the change range divider and then make the drag such that your mouse exists the browser screen, and then do a mouse_up outside the browser, this will trigger some action inside the stage , i.e make the range stick to the position it was, when the mouse exited the window.)

How can this be done in Flex 3/4??

Thanks,

Neeraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, check);
```